# How to make sum over complex root pair real valued?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I have a characteristic equation which contains pair of complex conjugate roots:

```
chPoly = 1279 - 508 \[Lambda] - 58 \[Lambda]^2 + 
   12 \[Lambda]^3 - \[Lambda]^4;
(roots = SolveValues[chPoly == 0, \[Lambda]]) // N
(complexPair = roots[[{3, 4}]]) // N
```

with output

> ```
> %Out[2]={-5.15901, 2.17629, 7.49136 - 7.60239 I, 7.49136 + 7.60239 I}
>
> %Out[3]={7.49136 - 7.60239 I, 7.49136 + 7.60239 I}
> ```

I know that sum over complex root pairs must yield real answer. In particular I know that the combinations have the following form (the coefficients in numerator and denominator can be computed from characteristic equation itself)

```
realSumComplex = (
  Exp[r1] (324 - 136 r1 - 4 r1^2))/(-508 - 116 r1 + 36 r1^2 - 4 r1^3) + (
  Exp[r2] (324 - 136 r2 - 4 r2^2))/(-508 - 116 r2 + 36 r2^2 - 4 r2^3)
```

And it is indeed real

```
(realSumComplex /. {r1 -> complexPair[[1]], r2 -> complexPair[[2]]}) //
  N
```

> `%Out[5] 2307.48 + 0. I`

Since real combinations have structure

```
ComplexExpand[
  Exp[a + I*b] (c + I d)/(g + I h) + 
   Exp[a - I*b] (c - I d)/(g - I h)] // FullSimplify
```

> `%Out[6] (2 E^a ((c g + d h) Cos[b] + (-d g + c h) Sin[b]))/(g^2 + h^2)`

I can take real and complex parts of exponent, numerator polynomial, denominator polynomial and substitute them in the formula above.

```
realSumComplexParts = (termH[numH[complexPair], 
     numH[(Numerator[#] /. Exp[_] :> 1) & /@ (List @@ 
         realSumComplex)], 
     numH[(Denominator[#] /. Exp[_] :> 1) & /@ (List @@ 
         realSumComplex)]] /. {r1 -> complexPair[[1]], 
     r2 -> complexPair[[2]]}) /. {numH[
     crPair_] :> {(1/2) (Plus @@ crPair), (I/2) (Subtract @@ crPair)}}

termHDef[{expRe_, expIm_}, {numRe_, numIm_}, {denomRe_, denomIm_}] := 
 2 Exp[RootReduce[
    expRe]]*(RootReduce[numRe*denomRe + numIm*denomIm]*
      Cos[RootReduce[expIm]] + 
     RootReduce[-numIm*denomRe + numRe*denomIm]*
      Sin[RootReduce[expIm]])/RootReduce[denomRe^2 + denomIm^2]

(realSumComplexParts /. termH -> termHDef) // N
```

> `%Out[9] 2307.48`

I am not quite happy with this approach, since `RootReduce[ ]` takes a lot of time even for characteristic polynomial of degree `n=4`, whereas I want to make "realification" for n=32.
I don't think it is possible to completely avoid `RootReduce[]`, but may be if one can get rid of complex parts in a wiser way or use `RootReduce[]` in a more optimized way. Note that I need an exact answer in terms of `Root[]` objects.

Comment: Doesn't Vietta's formulas help here? `roots = SolveValues[chPoly == 0, \[Lambda]] // ToRadicals;Total[roots]`  results in `12`. Then use `realroots = SolveValues[chPoly == 0, \[Lambda], Reals] // ToRadicals`. Good luck!

Comment: @user64494 That is not what I want. I need RootSum[
  1279 - 508 # - 58 #^2 + 
    12 #^3 - #^4 &, (Exp[#] (324 - 136 # - 4 #^2))/(-508 - 116 # + 
      36 #^2 - 4 #^3) &]. This sum is real valued and is OK. However after converting it to Root[] objects (using Normal[]) we get complex valued answer which I want to avoid.Vietta's formulas compute  RootSum[
  1279 - 508 # - 58 #^2 + 
    12 #^3 - #^4 &, #&].

Comment: You can get the real and imaginary parts directly as `Root` by `{re, im} = RootReduce[ReIm[r1]]`. That should remove the numerical fuzz of cancelling imaginary parts.